# Asymptotic distribution of sample variance via multivariate delta method

Tags: variance, asymptotics, delta-method

I was trying to get the asymptotic distribution of sample variance using multivariate delta method and without normality assumption.

So I defined the random vector $ z = \left( \begin{matrix}
   X  \\
   X^2  \\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$ and the function $g$ which acts on components : $$g(z_1,z_2)=z_2 - z_1^2 $$
Clearly $g(E[z])=\sigma_X^2$.

Taking a random sample, the random vector: $z_n= \left( \begin{matrix}
   \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i \\
   \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i^2  \\
\end{matrix} \right) $ a plugin estimator for $\sigma_X^2$ is  $g(z_n)=S_X^2 $ (sample variance).

Knowing that $z_n$ converges asymptotically to a normal distribution thanks to central limit theorem:
 $${{z}_{n}}\xrightarrow{d}N\left( E[z],\frac{1}{n}\left( \begin{matrix}
   V[X] & \operatorname{cov}(X,{{X}^{2}})  \\
   \operatorname{cov}({{X}^{2}},X) & V[{{X}^{2}}]  \\
\end{matrix} \right) \right)
 $$ 
we  can apply multivariate delta method.

---

I get stuck in the estimation of variance by delta method which should be 
$$({{\left. \nabla g \right|}_{E[X]}})^t \left( \begin{matrix}
   V[X] & \operatorname{cov}(X,{{X}^{2}})  \\
   \operatorname{cov}({{X}^{2}},X) & V[{{X}^{2}}]  \\
\end{matrix} \right){{\left. \nabla g \right|}_{E[X]}} $$
with
${{\left. \nabla g \right|}_{E[X]}} = \left( \begin{matrix}
   -2E[X]  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right) $ .

Performing the matrix product as above I end up with an asymptotic variance which does not match the one I found on textbooks , which is:
$$V[(X-E[X])^2]$$
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
   -2E[X] & 1\end{matrix}\right) 
\left(\begin{matrix}
   V[X] & Cov(X,X^2)  \\
   Cov(X^2,X) & V[X^2]  
\end{matrix}\right) 
\left(\begin{matrix}
   -2E[X]  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$$$
=\left(\begin{matrix}-2E[X]V[X] + Cov(X^2,X) & -2E[X]Cov(X^2,X)+V[X^2]\end{matrix}\right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   -2E[X]  \\
   1  
\end{matrix}\right) 
=4E^2[X]V[X] -4E[X]Cov(X^2,X)+V[X^2]
$$

$\begin{align}V[(X-E[X])^2] &= V[X^2 - 2XE[X] + E^2[X]\\ 
                            &= V(X^2) +(-2E(X))^2V(X) +V(E(X^2))\\ &\qquad -2Cov(X^2,2XE[X]) + 2Cov(X^2,E^2(X))\\&\qquad -2Cov(-2XE(X), E^2(X))\\
     =&4E^2[X]V[X] -4E[X]Cov(X^2,X)+V[X^2]\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you, that was really straightforward, I don't know why I got stuck in evaluating the term $ cov(X^2,2XE[X])$